# Get Position of selected checkbox AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to retrieve the position of a checked value :

HTML:

```
   <div ng-repeat="i in range(Data.nop)">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">

                   Option {{i}})

<br>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="score1[i-1]" ng-value="{{i-1}}"  name="score1"/>
                <br>
{{score1}}
            <textarea  ng-model="options[i-1]" class="form-control"></textarea>


                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.score1=[];
```

Comment: What are you mean about *position of checked value*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves my initial problem:

#### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="i in range(Data.nop)">
    <div class="form-group">
                   
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            Option {{i}})
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="score1[i-1]"  name="score1" ng-value="{{i-1}}" ng-true-value="'checked'" ng-false-value="'unchecked'"/>
            <br>
            <textarea  ng-model="options[i-1]" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
    $scope.options=[];
    $scope.score1=[];
    $scope.scores=[];

    angular.forEach($scope.score1,function(value,key){
        if (value ==='checked'){
            $scope.scores.push(key);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Accept you own answe if this is solving the initial problem. Please be so kind to format you questions better and provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish.